# How to use string values of a variable as a django model queries?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have some Model Fields those are related to User model by many to many relationship

```
class SocialPost(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='users_post' )
    privacy=models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True, null= True)
    post_text=models.TextField(blank=True, null= True)
    location=models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True, null= True)
    feeling_or_activity=models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True, null= True)
    created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at=models.DateTimeField(blank=True,null=True)
    category=models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True, null= True)
    tags=models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='taglist',blank=True)
    views = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='post_views',blank=True)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name='post_likes',blank=True)
    love=models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name='post_loves',blank=True)
    angry=models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name='post_angries',blank=True)
    haha=models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name='post_hahas',blank=True)
    sad=models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name='post_sads',blank=True)
    care=models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name='post_cares',blank=True)
    senti=models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name='post_senties',blank=True)
    wow=models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name='post_wows',blank=True)
```

I will get values like
`reaction='wow'` through API call.
i want to call like
`variable=object.reaction.filter()`
Which will be always call by reaction variables value.
as example if reaction='like'
it will call
`variable=object.like.all()`
and if reaction='sad'
it will call
`variable=object.sad.all()`

i don't know how can i do this!
can anyone help me in this problem?

Comment: E.g If i press like button then what do you want ? Do you want list of users who have clicked like for that post?

Comment: clicking like or love button will be handled by react.js developer. i will just take category of button clicked, for example: sad, love,wow.

Comment: And what do you want to return for that API?

Comment: yes if you click like button i will list down you to 'like' field. if you press love button then i will remove you from like list and add to love list. that is my criteria. but how can i know which button do you click?  i can use switch case  in this case. but i don't want to do this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [getattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr).

> Return the value of the named attribute of object. name must be a string.

If this is your input:

```py
reaction = 'sad'
```

And this is your `SocialPost` instance:

```py
obj = SocialPost(...)  # Avoid using "object" as a variable name because it is a Python keyword
```

You can then list all related `User` records:

```py
reacted_users = getattr(obj, reaction).all()  # Equivalent to <obj.sad.all()>
```

If you don't have any validation of the `reaction` field, you may be interested in [hasattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hasattr) e.g. `hasattr(obj, reaction)` to verify if the value is a recognized attribute of `SocialPost`.

Comment: `getattr(obj, reaction).all()` worked in my case.. Thank you so much

Comment: Glad it helped you. If it's all the answer you need, you may want to mark it as the accepted answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers :)

Comment: Ok , i have marked it as accepted. Thank you again